# ESX 5.5 Maximum File Size

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter, vmfs

We have a `~24TB Datastore` (a single LUN mapped via a DAS) which has a `VMFS5` Datastore.

My understanding was with ESX 5.5 and VMFS5 you can have file sizes up to 62TB (as per this article: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2058287) .

However, the properties of the datastore show the following:

[image]

Is there a configuration I am missing, is something wrong here?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: Was this datastore upgraded from VMS 3?

Comment: No, it was a brand new datastore on a new MD1200 expansion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolved. When looking at the datastore through the vSphere Web Interface (my fault, I still prefer the old client) it correctly shows the 62TB max size limit. Potentially a hardcoded value in the old GUI given it's now deprecated.

Comment: Exactly. In the KB article that you referenced there is also the sentence "You must use the vSphere Web Client to create or extend a VMDK beyond 2 TB".

Comment: Aye, but I didnt realise the GUI would actually report inaccurate information.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a former VMFS-3 volume. The block size impacts the maximum capacity of the datastore under the legacy VMFS-3 format.

[image]

But beyond that and with vSphere 5.5, you have to use the Web client to do anything with larger VMs and VMDKs.

> Use the vSphere Web Client to create VMDKs larger than 4 TB, or to
>   extend an existing VMDK beyond 4 TB.

Comment: I thought it might have been an upgraded VMFS 3 datastore as well, but it looks like 1MB is the non-configurable block size for VMFS 5. - http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003565